# How to change the step in lsqcurvefit in Matlab?

Tags: matlab

I'm having the following error :

```
lsqcurvefit stopped because the size of the current step is less than
the default value of the step size tolerance.
```

The step size tolerance is default (1e-6). The problem is I'm working with huge functions in X (a step in X = 1e7). The lsqcurvefit does not converge at all, as you could guess.

How can I modify the step so it might converge more easily?

Here's the creation of the Lorentzien:

```
Gamma=[4e6 4e6 4e6];
C=1;
m=0;
Amplitude=[1.5 5];
Width=[0.15 0.25];
Offset=[1 2];
GuessC=Offset;

Aub = 2e7;
Alb = 5e6;
NUub = FreqR*0.999;
NUlb = FreqR*0.800;


for i=1:Nombre
    Ampl(i,1) = Alb + (Aub-Alb).*rand;
    Ampl(i,2) = Alb + (Aub-Alb).*rand;
    Ampl(i,3) = Alb + (Aub-Alb).*rand;
    Pic1 = RoundTo(NUlb + (NUub-NUlb).*rand,-6);
    Pic2 = RoundTo(NUlb + (NUub-NUlb).*rand,-6);
    Pic3 = RoundTo(NUlb + (NUub-NUlb).*rand,-6);

    T0=[Ampl(i,1) Ampl(i,2) Ampl(i,3)];
    nurG(i,1) = min([Pic1 Pic2 Pic3]);
    nurG(i,2) = median([Pic1 Pic2 Pic3]);
    nurG(i,3) = max([Pic1 Pic2 Pic3]);
    X1=nurG(i,1)-FreqR*0.025:FreqR*0.0003:FreqR;
    N=length(X1);
    Y1=zeros(1,N);

    for j=1:N   
       Y1(j)=(2*T0(1)/pi)*(Gamma(1)/(4*(X1(j)-nurG(i,1))^2+Gamma(1)^2))+(2*T0(2)/pi)*(Gamma(2)/(4*(X1(j)-nurG(i,2))^2+Gamma(2)^2))+(2*T0(3)/pi)*(Gamma(3)/(4*(X1(j)-nurG(i,3))^2+Gamma(3)^2))+C+m*randn();
    end

XP1 = X1/(FreqR*0.009);

Frequency=[nurG(i,1)/(FreqR*0.009) nurG(i,3)/(FreqR*0.009)];
GuessP11=(Width./(2*pi)).*(Amplitude-Offset);
GuessP21=Frequency;
GuessP31=Width.^2/4;
GuessP12=(Width./(2*pi)).*(Amplitude-Offset);
GuessP22=Frequency;
GuessP32=Width.^2/4;
GuessP13=(Width./(2*pi)).*(Amplitude-Offset);
GuessP23=Frequency;
GuessP33=Width.^2/4;

[yprime params resnorm residual]=lorentzfit3(XP1,Y1,[],[GuessP11(1) GuessP21(1) GuessP31(1) GuessP12(1) GuessP22(1) GuessP32(1) GuessP13(1) GuessP23(1) GuessP33(1) GuessC(1); GuessP11(2) GuessP21(2) GuessP31(2) GuessP12(2) GuessP22(2) GuessP32(2) GuessP13(2) GuessP23(2) GuessP33(2) GuessC(2)]);
```

In lorentzfit3, there is a series of if to see if the Guess are right. But I'll skip that part. The Guess gives an idea where to start looking.

```
[params resnorm residual] = lsqcurvefit(@lfun3c,p0,x,y,lb,ub,optimset('MaxFunEvals',200000,'MaxIter',10000,'TolFun',1e-18));
yprime = lfun3c(params,x);

end % MAIN

function F = lfun3c(p,x)
F = p(1)./((x-p(2)).^2+p(3)) + p(4)./((x-p(5)).^2+p(6)) + p(7)./((x-p(8)).^2+p(9)) + p(10);
end % LFUN3C
```

Comment: You can use optimset('lsqcurvefit') to get the lsqcurvefit options structure, change whatever values you want, and then supply that structure in your lsqcurvefit call. However, I suspect that any convergence problems you are having will not be helped by changing options.

Comment: The step size tolerance can be modified, but it won't help converging indeed. And the size of the steps cannot be modified this way as far as I know.

Comment: I cannot run your code as you did not define `FreqR` and `Nombre`. Also, could you plot your `Y1` array - I tried some values for `FreqR` and got essentially "all three peaks on top of each other". That makes it impossible to get the fit to work... the spacing between peaks must be greater than the width or you're fighting a losing battle. Also please show how `lorentzfit3` is defined (at least show the first line of the function - otherwise it's hard to guess how `lsqcurvefit` is called.

Answer (score 1):

You can rewrite your function so it takes a more reasonably scaled argument:

```
function f = myfun(x)
f = myBigFun(1e7 * x);
```

Where myBigFun is your original function - but now myfun has an x that is scaled over a smaller range of steps.

The same is a good idea when you look at the values a function returns; sometimes optimization cannot see changes of the order you are interested in, so again, scaling the output of your function to a "reasonable range" helps ensure "things behave".

Another thing that often makes sense, especially when your optimum is "somewhere around a very big number", is re-centering your function: rather than exploring from 1000000 to 1000001, you center your function so you are searching for a value between -0.5 and 0.5

Just some thoughts that should help you on your way...

Comment: Well, I tried that, but it didn't help at all.

As I said, the problem is that lsqcurvefit will stop anyway because his steps are under the step size tolerance. The function doesn't converge at all.

Comment: My function goes from -10 to 10 now, instead of 2.6e9 to 3.5e9.

Comment: Can you update your question to show the function that is giving the problem, and the way you are scaling it? Maybe that will give me some other ideas.